# Apparent limit to re.findall in Python

Tags: python, regex, data-analysis

I have a file containing data (defining some mathematical objects) in a format which is inconvenient and I would like to convert it to JSON using Python 3. Since the file is huge (it contains 921,497 objects, each needing several lines to be defined), I used the module `mmap` to load content that I analyse using `re.findall`. My problem is that I get only the first 99999 entries, and I am wondering where does the limit come from? I don't get any error and I could not find an explanation for this.

I have made some small tests to find limits, but the number I obtained are much bigger than 99999:

```
>>> import re
>>> len(re.search(r"a{1,9999999}", "a"*(2*10**6)).group())
2000000
>>> len(re.findall(r"a", "a"*(2*10**6)))
2000000
>>> import sre_constants
>>> sre_constants.MAXGROUPS
2147483647
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to surpass this limit, or of a better approach to collect the data?

---

My code (up to saving the files) is the following:

```
"""
Transform dataset for CICY 4-fold to JSON

arxiv: 1303.1832
http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/projects/CalabiYau/Cicy4folds/index.html
"""

import os, mmap, json, tarfile, tempfile
import regex as re

CICY4_REGEX = b"""\
MATRIX NUMBER :\s+(\d+)
SIZE :\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)
EULERNUMBER :\s+(\d+)
([\d\s\|]+)
"""
cicy4_pattern = re.compile(CICY4_REGEX, re.MULTILINE)

json_data = {}
last_ind = 0

with open('cicy4folds.txt', 'r') as f,\
        mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as m:

    for data in cicy4_pattern.findall(m):

        dic = {"vec": [], "matrix": []}

        ind = int(data[0])
        if ind != last_ind + 1:
            print(ind)
        last_ind = ind

        #dic["id"] = int(data[0])
        dic["size"] = (int(data[1]), int(data[2]))
        dic["euler"] = int(data[3])

        for line in data[4].decode("utf-8").split("\n")[:-1]:
            ind, row = line.split(" | ")
            dic["vec"].append(int(ind))
            dic["matrix"].append(list(map(int, row.split())))

        json_data[int(data[0])] = dic

print("Size: ", len(json_data))
```

The file `cicy4folds.txt` can be found [here](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/projects/CalabiYau/Cicy4folds/index.html). Here are two examples of data:

```
MATRIX NUMBER : 26538
SIZE :   6 10
EULERNUMBER :  480
1 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 | 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 | 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 | 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 | 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

MATRIX NUMBER : 26539
SIZE :   6  4
EULERNUMBER :  720
1 | 0 0 0 2
1 | 0 0 0 2
1 | 0 0 1 1
1 | 0 0 1 1
2 | 1 1 0 1
2 | 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: have you tried `for data in cicy4_pattern.finditer(m):` instead?

Comment: I tried and in this case I get just 9 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your regex :)

You could change it to:

```
 CICY4_REGEX = b"""\
 MATRIX NUMBER :\s*(\d+)
 SIZE :\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)
 EULERNUMBER :\s+(\d+)
 ([\d\s\|]+)
 """
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid because I already missed around 1000 examples from the first 100000 due to a similar mistake in the regex. I just did not believe they would not include spaces at this place…